# Laravel 5.1 query about relationship's foreign key's attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship, laravel-5.1

So let's say I have three Models

> - Country
> - Company
> - Department
> - Worker

I have the following obvious relationships:

```
Country::hasMany('Companies');
Company::hasMany('Department');
Department::hasMany('Worker');

Country::hasManyThrough('Department', 'Company');
Company::hasManyThrough('Worker', 'Department');
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is getting all the `Departments` of a `Country`, where there's a `Worker` with a `salary` more than 10000.

So basically I'm looking for a Relationship, where I can call a `where` function on the foreign relationship.

Something like this:

```
Country::find(1)->departments()->where('...', '>=', 10000);
```

I thought about trying to create a scope function to the model `Department`, but didn't really know what do write there:

```
public function scopeSalary($query, $salary)
{
     return $query->somethingHere()->where('salary', '>=', $salary);
}
```

Then I know that I could do it with the  [Join statement in query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins), but I think it might be a bit bad practice. I would like to know if there's a way in Laravel I could call a `where` function on the relationships foreign key model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whereHas 
http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas

```
Country::find(1)->departments()->whereHas('workers', function($q) {
   $q->where('salary', '>=', 10000);
})->get();
```

Comment: I wanted to add, that in order to use a variable inside the function, you must use the 'use' keyword. For example, if you had the variable $salary, that you wanted to use in the function, you can use it like this:

`Country::find(1)->departments()->whereHas('workers', function($q) use ($salary){

   $q->where('salary', '>=', $salary);

})->get();`